# extracting data between specific dates in timseries using ts() function

Tags: r, time-series, training-data

I want to separate train and test set out of  a single time series and i need to handle with DAILY dates. As I'm trying to separate, it doesn't work, the code shown put all data to the train set.
My data starts from 2000/01/03 till 2023/09/21 and i want to subset from beginning till 2016/09/30 as a train.

RUT_data_org <- read.csv("RUT.csv")

RUT_data$Date <- as.Date(RUT_data_org$Date,format = ("%d-%m-%Y"))

RUT_data<-diff(RUT_data_org$Close,difference=1)

RUT_train <- RUT_data[1:4200]

RUT_test<-RUT_data[4201:6010]

RUT_ts_tr <- ts(RUT_train[1:4200], start = c(2000,1), end = c(2016,9), frequency = 365)

RUT_ts_te <- ts(RUT_test[4201:6010], start = c(2016, 10), end = c(2023,11), frequency = 365)

Answer (score 0):

The input is missing from the question so we will use the input shown in the Note.  If there are differences between that and what you have you will need to adapt the code.

Assuming that RUT is the Russell 2000 ETF note that `"ts"` class requires regularly spaced data with an equal number of points per cycle so if a cycle is one year it can't be used with ts without some additional preprocessing such as interpolating the missing data on the weekends and holidays, throwing away points so each year has the same number and numbering the points sequentially,  reducing the data to monthly, using 1, 2, 3, ... as the times with frequency 1  or not using ts.  We will use times of 1, 2, 3, ... with frequency 1.

Using the reproducible data in the Note at the end read in the data, extract the Close column and difference it.  Note the gaps in the date sequence.  To continue with ts we shall replace the dates with 1, 2, 3, ... and frequency 1.

```
library(quantmod)

RUT.dif <- "RUT.csv" |>
  read.csv.zoo(format = "%d-%m-%Y") |>
  Cl() |>
  diff()

# note gaps
table(diff(time(RUT.dif))) # note gaps, e.g. there is one gap of 7 days.
##    1    2    3    4    5    7 
## 4673   55 1076  158    2    1 

RUT.ts <- ts(RUT.dif) # use 1, 2, 3, ... for times
ix <- round(2/3 * length(RUT.ts))
RUT.train <- window(RUT.ts, end = ix)
RUT.test <- window(RUT.ts, start = ix + 1)
```

Other possibilities are to use zoo or xts which will preserve the dates.  This uses the zoo object `RUT.dif` from above.

```
ix <- round(2/3 * length(RUT.dif))
RUT.train <- RUT.dif[1:ix]
RUT.test <- RUT.dif[-(1:ix)]
```

### Note

```
# create test data

library(quantmod)

getSymbols("^RUT", from = "2000-01-03", to = "2023-09-21")
RUT.df <- as.data.frame(RUT)
rownames(RUT.df) <- format(time(RUT), "%d-%m-%Y")
write.csv(RUT.df, "RUT.csv")
```

Comment: Very informative, thanks. I've tried ts() by setting frequency to 255 and it works!  I will try yours, thanks again